# Is silent lazy loading of children nodes possible in Dynatree?

Tags: lazy-loading, silent, dynatree

From breadcrumbs, I'm using Dynatree's `getNodeByKey()` API function to access a tree node and `appendAjax` to append children to it:

```
<?php
  (...)
   parentNode=tree.getNodeByKey(parent);
    parentNode.appendAjax({
      type: \'POST\',
      url: \'inc/treeNodes.php\',
      dataType: \'json\',
      data: {key: parent}
    });
?>
```

Using the code above, there is a **side effect** ; it is like if the parent node gets focus and my page auto-scrolls up to display the tree.

What should I do to make the lazy loading completely silent?

Answer (score 0):

Dynatree is no longer maintained. However, the successor [Fancytree](https://github.com/mar10/fancytree) supports the [`node.load()`](http://www.wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/doc/jsdoc/FancytreeNode.html#load) method, that may solve your problem if [updating](https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/wiki/WhatsNew) is an option for you.